# UDP packet send using pcap shows up in Wireshark but does not arrive at a socket

Tags: c++, networking, udp, boost-asio, pcap

I have just started with socket programming so it may be that I am missing something trivial, but even after many Google searches and trying out various things I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am working on a linux computer, but the code provided here should compile on Windows as well.

Before I elaborate on my problem I will first explain what I have done so far. I have a program that listens for one incoming UDP packet on a loopback interface IP address (127.1.0.0:4365). The source code is as follows (I am actually using the non-boost version of asio, but that shouldn't matter):

```
#include <asio.hpp>
using asio::ip::udp;

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    asio::io_service io_service;

    udp::socket sock(io_service,
            udp::endpoint(asio::ip::address::from_string("127.1.0.0"), 4365));

    char data[128];
    udp::endpoint senderEndpoint;
    size_t length = sock.receive_from(asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)),
                                      senderEndpoint);

    printf("Received '%s' (%zu bytes) from %s.\n", data, length,
           senderEndpoint.address().to_string().data());

    return 0;
}
```

When I use a program that sends one UDP packet using sockets, the listener receives the UDP packet correctly. The source code is:

```
#include <asio.hpp>
using asio::ip::udp;

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    const uint8_t data[] = "Hello!";
    asio::io_service io_service;
    uint16_t port = 4365;

    asio::ip::address address = asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1");
    udp::socket sock(io_service, udp::endpoint(address, port));

    address = asio::ip::address::from_string("127.1.0.0");
    udp::endpoint destination(address, port);

    bool success = (sock.send_to(asio::buffer(data, sizeof(data)), destination)
                                                            == sizeof(data));

    if (success)
        printf("Packet sent.\n");
    else
        printf("Error sending packet.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Now for the problem that I am facing. I need to receive packets from a sender that uses the pcap library. When I use the following source code to construct and send a UDP packet, I can see with Wireshark that the packet is going out, and apart from the IP identification and IP checksum the packet is identical to the one sent using the socket program.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pcap/pcap.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t checksum(const uint8_t* buf, uint nbytes, uint32_t sum)
{
    uint i;
    for (i = 0; i < (nbytes & ~1U); i += 2) {
        sum += *(uint16_t*)(buf + i);
        if (sum > 0xFFFF)
            sum -= 0xFFFF;
    }

    // checksum the last byte if present
    if (i < nbytes) {
        sum += buf[i];
        if (sum > 0xFFFF)
            sum -= 0xFFFF;
    }

    return sum;
}

uint16_t ipChecksum(const uint8_t* const packet)
{
    uint32_t sum = 0;
    sum = checksum(packet + 14, 20, sum);

    return ~sum;
}

uint16_t udpChecksum(const uint8_t* packet, int /*userDataLength*/)
{
    // protocol and UDP length
     uint32_t sum = htons(0x0011) + *(uint16_t*)(packet + 38);

#if 0
    // this is supposed to be the right way to calculate the UDP checksum, but
    // the result is not the same as when sockets are used
    sum = checksum(packet + 26, 14, sum); // IP source, destination, UDP header
    sum = checksum(packet + 42, userDataLength, sum); // user data

    return ~sum;
 #else
    // this calculation results in the same UDP checksum as calculated by the
    // socket library
     sum = checksum(packet + 26, 8, sum); // IP source, destination

    return sum;
#endif
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    printf("[pcap] Sending 'Hello!' to 127.1.0.0:4365 from 127.0.0.1:4365\n");

    const uint8_t data[] = "Hello!";

    // create the interface, configure, and activate
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
    pcap_t* handle = pcap_create("lo", errbuf);
    if (handle == nullptr) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", errbuf);
        return -1;
    }
    if (pcap_activate(handle) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to activate the interface, try running as root.\n");
         return -1;
    }

    // create the packet
    int packetLength = 42 + sizeof(data);
    uint8_t* packet = new uint8_t[packetLength]; // header is 42 bytes

    // Ethernet II header
    memset(packet, 0, 6); // destination MAC
    memset(packet + 6, 0, 6); // source MAC
    memcpy(packet + 12, "\x08\x00", 2); // EtherType IPv4

    // IP Header
    memcpy(packet + 14, "\x45", 1); // version and header length
    memcpy(packet + 15, "\x00", 1); // services
    uint16_t tmp = htons(20 + 8 + sizeof(data)); // length = IP + UDP + data
    memcpy(packet + 16, &tmp, 2);
    memcpy(packet + 18, "\x00\x00", 2);// identification
    memcpy(packet + 20, "\x40", 1); // flags
    memcpy(packet + 21, "\x00", 1); // fragmentation offset
    memcpy(packet + 22, "\x40", 1); // time to live
    memcpy(packet + 23, "\x11", 1); // UDP protocol
    memcpy(packet + 24, "\x00\x00", 2); // checksum
    memcpy(packet + 26, "\x7F\x00\x00\x01", 4); // source IP
    memcpy(packet + 30, "\x7F\x01\x00\x00", 4); // destination IP
    tmp = ipChecksum(packet);
    memcpy(packet + 24, &tmp, 2); // checksum

     // UDP Header
    memcpy(packet + 34, "\x11\x0D", 2); // source port 4365
    memcpy(packet + 36, "\x11\x0D", 2); // destination port 4365
    tmp = htons(8 + sizeof(data)); // length = UDP header size + data size
    memcpy(packet + 38, &tmp, 2);
    memcpy(packet + 40, "\x00\x00", 2); // checksum

    // user data
    memcpy(packet + 42, data, sizeof(data));

    // calculate the UDP checksum
    tmp = udpChecksum(packet, sizeof(data));
    memcpy(packet + 40, &tmp, 2); // checksum

     // send the packet
    bool success = (pcap_inject(handle, packet, packetLength) == packetLength);

    pcap_close(handle);
    delete packet;

    if (success)
        printf("Packet sent!\n");
    else
        printf("Error sending packet\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Although Wireshark shows the packet, and the packet is almost identical to the one sent by the socket program, the listener fails to receive it. Even if I use the same IP identification so the packets are identical it doesn't work.

The obvious solution would be to write a listener using the pcap library, but sockets are much nicer to work with.

Anyway, I will be grateful to anyone who can help me to figure out how I can make this work.

Comment: If you generate an identical pcap packet, can you confirm that the ethernet headers (e.g. MAC addresses) are identical too?

Comment: Yes, Wireshark shows the complete packet including the Ethernet header, and I confirmed that the packets are identical.

Comment: Try to set up two different systems to test the send and receive. The only thing I can think of is that pcap inserts the packet below the loopback adapter level, which causes it not being able to reach your receiver. A side note: I would not recommend use of the [127.1.0.0](https://www.quora.com/Is-127-1-a-valid-IP-address) address.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But in the end I'd like to make it work using the loopback as well. What is the reason that I should avoid 127.1.0.0? I read the article you linked to, but clearly 127.1 is different from 127.1.0.0?